# Chartist not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chartist.js, angular-chartist.js

I am trying to use the [Chartist.js](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html) framework to create charts and graphs for my site. But for some reason I keep getting the error "Chartist is not defined"

I can't figure out how to fix this error. Please see the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chartist.js - Simple line chart</title>
    <script>
       // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
       new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
       labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
       series: [
                 [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
                 [0, 2.5, 3, 2, 3],
                 [1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4]
               ]
        }, {
          width: 500,
          height: 300
       });

     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
     <div class="ct-chart"></div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move your scripts to the footer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="https//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chartist.js - Simple line chart</title>

     </head>

     <body>
     <div class="ct-chart"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
       new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
       labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
       series: [
                 [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
                 [0, 2.5, 3, 2, 3],
                 [1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4]
               ]
        }, {
          width: 500,
          height: 300
       });

     </script>
     </body>

     </html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3sAdiBJaaue3x9kgBRZw?p=preview

And it's working like a charm :)

Comment: This does not work in IE 11 for me. I get 'Chartist' is undefined. Works nicely in Chrome, though.

Comment: Weird, it works on a Win 10 machine, but not on the WIn 7 machine.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson in Win 10 IE uses Edge engine to render websites. I'm not sure though why it's not working in Win 7.